# Pushing a certain amount of flow through a graph and vertice flow distributions close to some target vector

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Let's say I'm designing fictional fruits. The fruits have two attributes, color and taste. There are $n$ possible colors and $m$ possible tastes. Further, we're given an $n \times m$ feasibility matrix dictating which colors are compatible with which tastes.

I want to create exactly $f$ fruits. Also, I have a vector of colors, $c$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i = f$ and a vector of tastes, $t$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m t_i = f$.

I want the $f$ fruits to be created in a way that the final distribution of colors across the $f$ fruits is as close to $c$ as possible and that of tastes is as close to $t$ as possible. Concretely, let's say the actual distribution of colors across the $f$ fruits is given by $\hat{c}$ and that of tastes is $\hat{t}$, we want to minimize:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (c-\hat{c})^2 + \sum_{j=1}^m (t-\hat{t})^2$$

What clever algorithms from graph theory or elsewhere can be used to do this efficiently?

---

My attempt: the colors and tastes form a bi-partite graph. So, we imagine a source node, connected to all colors with capacities dictated by the $c$ vector, then the colors are connected to tastes per the feasibility matrix (capacities $\infty$) and the tastes are connected to a sink node again with capacities dictated by the $t$ vector. We run a max flow. Some colors and tastes are covered; we eliminate them and repeat until all are covered. But this is probably not optimal either (and more importantly) in terms of objective function or efficiency.

Comment: You'll need to specify your objective function more precisely. First, "as close as possible" is ambigious; second, you've said two objective functions and should specify how to combine them. (For instance, we could take the Euclidean distance between the fruit distribution and $c$, and add the Euclidean distance between the taste distribution and $t$.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov - added clarification. Sum of Euclidean distances is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be the set of all feasible fruit-taste pairs. For each $(i,j) \in E$, let $x_{ij}$ be the amount of fruit $i$ with taste $j$ produced. Then the "ideal constraints" are that

- for every fruit $i$, $\sum_{j : (i,j) \in E} x_{ij} = c_i$, and
- for every taste $j$, $\sum_{i: (i,j) \in E} x_{ij} = t_j$.

This is a system of linear equations $Ax = b$, with a nonnegativity constraint $x \ge 0$. Of course, it's probably not feasible, so it's not our actual feasible region.

For the objective function in the question, we are minimizing $\|Ax - b\|_2$ over all $x \ge 0$, which is a [non-negative least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares) problem. There's a variety of methods to solve this.

(I originally forgot about the constraint $\sum_{(i,j) \in E} x_{ij} = f$. To make sure that *this* constraint is satisfied exactly and doesn't get "relaxed" in the least squares, we can solve for one of the $x_{ij}$ variables in terms of the others.)

Other variants to consider:

- If we minimize $\|Ax-b\|_1$ instead (the sum of the absolute differences $|c_i - \hat{c}_i|$ and $|t_j - \hat{t}_j|$) then we can formulate the problem as a linear program: write $z_i \ge |c_i - \hat{c}_i|$ (a pair of linear constraints in the $x_{ij}$), $w_j \ge |t_j - \hat{t}_j|$ (another pair of linear constraints), and minimize $z_1 + \dots + z_n + w_1 + \dots + w_m$.
- If we additionally want each $x_{ij}$ to be an integer, things become much more complicated. In both cases, we can probably use some kind of branch-and-bound technique for integer programming.

Comment: It is indeed an integer programming problem. Also not that the total number of fruits has to be $f$. I was hoping there would be some clever max-flow type graph algorithms that can be leveraged so we can avoid integer programming.

Comment: I'd expect that to happen only if it turns out that solving the fractional relaxation of the problem spontaneously gives us integer solutions anyway.